# iterating over json with numeric key using $.each

Tags: jquery, json, each

I use an ajax call to pass a json from the server to the client.  The json has the following structure:

```
var data =
  {
     "2001":{"name":"tom", "age":33, "pos":"mk"},
     "3602":{"name":"cindy", "age":56, "pos":"cs"},
     "1060":{"name":"mike", "age":23, "pos":"mg"}
  }
```

I am trying to iterate over the object using $.each in jquery to access "name" and "pos" in the nested object.  For some reason I cannot even get through the first level (i.e. "2001", "3602", ...) of the object let alone deeper into it.  Here is the syntax I used to simply alert the numeric key.

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
alert(data[key]);
});
```

Nothing happens when I execute this code.  As such, when I try to run the following code to access all of the names nothing happens either:

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
   $.each(object, function(key, value){
   alert(data[key].name);
  });
 });
```

I know the javascript doesn't like numeric keys, but I have seen other people access data in numeric keys using data["2001"], so it seem possible to loop over a json structured this way.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Change `alert(data[key]);` to `alert(data[id]);` and it should work.

Comment: *"I know the javascript doesn't like numeric keys"* That's a misunderstanding on your side I believe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple....

```
 $.each(data, function(id, object){
  alert(data[id].name);
  alert(data[id].pos);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the parameter names `id` and `object`, then in the function you use the variable `key` right out of the blue, instead of the `id` parameter.

Use the `id` parameter to get the index:

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
  alert(data[id]);
});
```

or use the `object` parameter directly:

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
  alert(object);
});
```

In your second code you are using the `object` parameter correctly in the outer loop, but then you are trying to access members in the inner loop using `data[key]` instead of `object[key]`.

Use the `object` parameter to access the inner object:

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
  $.each(object, function(key, value){
    alert(object[key].name);
  });
});
```

or use the `value` parameter directly:

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
  $.each(object, function(key, value){
    alert(value.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$.each(data, function (id, object) {
     console.log(object.name);
    $.each(object, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key +"-"+value);
    });
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/GBntj/2/

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `key` is not defined.  This should probably be `data[id]`, but that is actually just the same as `object`, which has the `name` value you are looking for.

```
$.each(data, function(id, object){
    console.log(object.name);
});
```

That's enough to fix the problem, but let's discuss why your second example is wrong too.  You're iterating over `object`, but you're still trying to reference `data`.  The `key`s in `object` are different than those in `data`, so `data[key]` on the inner loop does not exist.  Using `object[key].name` would also be incorrect because it is *`object`* that has the `name` property, not its elements.